# IllegalMonitorStateException when creating an object

Tags: java, synchronization, java-native-interface, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I'm getting `IllegalMonitorStateException` when I'm trying to create an instance of an object. The code looks like the following:

```
public int signIn(parameters...)
{
  ...check some stuff...
  new Thread(... just a simple log here...).start();//IllegalMonitorStateException

  return result;
}
```

**MORE INFO:**
The actual application consists of 2 programs (C++ and java) interacting via JNI). The scenario in which I'm getting exception is as follows.

- The c++ program asks java to connect to a server. (this is a non blocking operation)
- Java program informs c++ about connection success. (in a new thread so that java can continue doing other tasks)
- When receiving connection success, c++ program asks java to login
- Exception occurs.

I should note that this exception only happens in this special scenario and if I call login sometime after connection success everything works fine.

*What I've tried:*

- In the beginning informing connection success was not in a new thread, but creating the thread did not solve the problem.
- The java login code had some synchronization stuff but removing them and replacing it with a simple log still produces the problem.

**EDIT:**
Here's the stacktrace:

> Phoenix.client.ClientAPI.NativeInterface.NativeAPIEventListener.onConnectingFinished(Native
>   Method)
>   Phoenix.client.ClientAPI.NativeInterface.NativeAPIEventListener.access$000(NativeAPIEventListener.java:12)
>   Phoenix.client.ClientAPI.NativeInterface.NativeAPIEventListener$1.run(NativeAPIEventListener.java:30)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You gave a lot of irrelevant information, but failed to provide the essentials: exception stacktrace and the exact code lines pointed out by the stacktrace.

Comment: I copied the stack trace, but it does not contain valid info. That's because a java thread has gone into c++ and thus lost its context. So when c++ calls back in java again the call stack doesn't contain valid info. What you're seeing the stack trace is the trace before calling in c++.

Comment: But without that you can't expect strangers to be of any help, can you? All we can say is that your Java callback code executed one of `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` without holding the target's monitor, or even directly instantiated and threw `IllegalMonitorStateException`. That information is quite useless to you, I presume.

Comment: Time to hit this question with the close hammer, I think.  The OP is not getting the message.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There is no `wait/notify/notifyAll` that's what's confusing me.

Comment: But you are clueless as to which line of your Java callback actually throws the exception? Why don't you try eliminating all possible suspects by commenting them out?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Correct, I don't know what line of code throws the exception I have only been able to trace it (by logging) to the point said in the question. I cannot go further since it will go in JVM code. What I suspect is that something in maybe the JVM is trying to work in a synchronized block, (When it is instantiating the new thread/runnable).

Comment: You have positively concluded that the line `new Thread(...).start()` throws the exception? Have you studied the documentation as to any restrictions about what Java code called from native code is allowed to do?

Comment: You could also catch the exception in the native code and try to get its stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, that is my best guess: Somewhere in creating the `new Runnable()` the exception occurs. I cannot catch the exception in c++ since the function returns normally (Whether I catch the exception in java or not it is not passed to c++).

Comment: You have isolated the `new Thread()` constructor code and `Thread.start()` code, pinpointing the problem to `new Runnable()` constructor code? That would be my last-resort guess. Both the `Thread` constructor and `start()` are complex methods with a lot going on, and `start` of course calling again back into native code to start a new native thread. The `Runnable` constructor is probably almost a no-op.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I posted a workaround and a possible cause, any comments?

Comment: Well, nothing much to add, you've got a mess of threads and java-native transitions. I have never done similar work so I have no experience to share with you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new thread in C++ code when java code called back into it This broke the `jthread:java -> c++ -> java` chain into `jthread:java -> c++` and `cthread:c++ -> java`. This solved the problem I was facing. However I ran into a different problem which lead me into reading a bit of JNI documentation. Quoting [JNI doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html):

> The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv) is valid only in the current
>   thread. **Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must
>   first call AttachCurrentThread() to attach itself to the VM and obtain
>   a JNI interface pointer**. Once attached to the VM, a native thread
>   works just like an ordinary Java thread running inside a native
>   method. The native thread remains attached to the VM until it calls
>   DetachCurrentThread() to detach itself.

So I guess I should've called `AttachCurrentThread` before calling back into java. However this does not exactly fit in the above description since the thread was not a native thread (it was a thread originally created in java code, could I call `DetachCurrentThread` afterwards?). I did not test this solution since I had to create a new thread other reasons too. But if I get a chance to try this out I'll confirm.